# Each value checked checkbox in var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've run into a bit of an issue. Here's a brief explanation.

I have 8 check boxes on a standard form. What I need to do is loop through each  value checked checkbox in var  .
But i got always the same value of the first checbox?

So far, I've got this bit of code.

```
var ref_idee = "";
        $('.ajaxupdate:checked').each(function () {
                var sThisVal = $( this.checked ).val();
            //var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $('.ajaxupdate').val());
            ref_idee += (ref_idee=="" ? sThisVal : "," + sThisVal);
        });
        console.log (ref_idee);
```

Comment: use `$(this).val()` and not `$( this.checked ).val()`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. If you had produced a [mcve] you would have seen this_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the typo `$(this.checked ).val();` instead of `$(this).val();`, you still have remnants of a useless and incorrect ternary only needed when all checkboxes were retrieved instead of only the checked ones

The complete code could be

```js
var ref_idee = [];
$('.ajaxupdate:checked').each(function() {
  ref_idee.push(this.value);
});
console.log(ref_idee.join(","));


//Or simpler

ref_idee = $('.ajaxupdate:checked').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(ref_idee.join(","));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="ajaxupdate" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" class="ajaxupdate" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="ajaxupdate" value="3" checked />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

Replace **$(this.checked).val();** to **$(this).val()**;

```
        var ref_idee = "";
        $('.ajaxupdate:checked').each(function () {
                var sThisVal = $(this).val();                
            ref_idee += (ref_idee=="" ? sThisVal : "," + sThisVal);
        });
        console.log (ref_idee);
```

Comment: The ternary is not needed. It's obviously a leftover from when all checkboxes were retrieved instead of only the checked ones